# How do I add both a form and a set key value pair into MongoDB using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, insert, keyvaluepair

I've got a system set up where a user can create an object (a jam) using a form.

I also want to add another key-value pair to this form on creation: jam_creator : session['username'], but I can't seem to figure out how to go about this using python.

Any help you be massively appreciated!

I've been messing around with update, insert, but none have worked.

```
@app.route('/add_jam')
    def add_jam():
        return render_template('addjam.html',
        instruments=mongo.db.instruments.find(),
        counties=mongo.db.counties.find(),
        username=session['username'])

@app.route('/insert_jam', methods=['POST'])
    def insert_jam():
        jams =  mongo.db.jam_or_event
        jams.insert_one(request.form.to_dict())

    print(request.form)
    return redirect(url_for('get_jams'))
```

The 'add_jam' is to bring up the form to fill out, the 'insert_jam' is to create an object with the contents of the form.